# Ruby Date.strftime format date with 19-1-1 to 1900-01-01 not work

Tags: ruby, date

**Using Ruby for Reading a sheet of Excel, I have a problem with the date format.**

My code is:

```
Date.strptime("19-1-1", "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%Y/%m/%d') /* i try this
'0019-01-01' /* result
```

I need:

```
'1900-01-01'
```

Any idea how to change?

Comment: There's no way '0019' can be converted to 1900, use `Date.strptime("1900-1-1", "%Y-%m-%d")` instead, if you need, concatenate the needed zeros.

Comment: but in Excel the date come in this format 17/01/01 when i use the code change 0017-01-01

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `19-1-1` is suppose to January 1st 1900 and not 2019? The latter seems much more likely to me...

Comment: Just i need 19 to 2019 thx this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming an error in your question.

You're parsing the date incorrectly. `%Y` is for the year *with century*, so "19" is just the year 19.

You want `%y` which is year *without century* ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime)). So it interprets "19" as the year 2019.

```
Date.strptime("19-1-1", "%y-%m-%d").strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
# "2019/01/01"
```